# How can I set the mouse cursor position in a UWP app?

Tags: .net, win-universal-app, mouse-cursor

There is the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position property which you can use to move the mouse, but you can't use that in a UWP app that does not use the .NET Framework.

Is there anything like this that you can use to move the mouse in a UWP app?

Answer (score 4):

As you know `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` can not be used in UWP. You can use `CoreWindow.PointerPosition` to set the location of mouse. The mouse can move to the new location, when you set the new `Point` to the `CoreWindow.PointerPosition`.

> You can not read the pointer position with this API when the lock screen is present.

For more info, see [CoreWindow.PointerPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.corewindow.pointerposition.aspx)

For example:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(500, 500);
```